# Rigorous proof for the converse of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \implies f $ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I need to prove that for a given function $ f $ continuous on $ [a,\infty)$ with $ a \in \mathbb{R}$, $ \exists\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \implies f $ is unif. continuous on $[a, \infty) $, which isn't to complicated after playing with epsilons and deltas. Now, I have to determine whether the reciprocal is true or not. That means determining if the following statement is true or not:

$ f $ unif. cont. $\implies \exists\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$

I have simply come up with a counterexample leveraging the fact that $ f(x) = x$ is unif. cont. but the limit doesn't exist.
My question is: **How do I prove the reciprocal is not true rigorously with epsilons and deltas?** I have attempted it, with little success.

All comments and critics are welcome

Comment: this is typically called the converse, not the reciprocal

Comment: and you show that the converse is not true by giving a counter example, as you have done.  you can show that the limit of x as x tends to infinity does not exist if you want to check that f(x) = x is indeed a counter example

Comment: you have to define in which interval $f$ is unif. cont. do you mean that $f$ is unif. cont in $[a, \infty)$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Jneven Yes, since we know it is continuous on $ [a, \infty) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a continuous function $f$, by the Weierstrass theorem we know that for every $a<b\in \mathbb{R}, f$ is uniformly continuous $[a,b]$.
if.

the function $f(x)=x$ is **not** uniformly continuous in $[a,\infty)$, exactly because $lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) \to \infty$.

This means that if the limit of a function $f$ as $x$ approaches infinity exists and and is finite, then $f$ is a unif cont function in $[a,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a link to Weierstrass's theorem ?

Comment: its called "boundedness theorem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Proof_of_the_boundedness_theorem]